# How to download zip file using Python scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to download zip file of [this](https://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=http://download.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Medicare-Provider-Charge-Data/Downloads/Medicare_National_HCPCS_Aggregate_CY2017.zip) link. I tried various method but I couldn't do this.

```
url = "https://www.cms.gov/apps/ama/license.asp?file=http://download.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Medicare-Provider-Charge-Data/Downloads/Medicare_National_HCPCS_Aggregate_CY2017.zip"

# downloading with requests

# import the requests library
import requests


# download the file contents in binary format
r = requests.get(url)

# open method to open a file on your system and write the contents
with open("minemaster1.zip", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)


# downloading with urllib

# import the urllib library
import urllib

# Copy a network object to a local file
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "minemaster.zip")
```

Can anybody help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're using some accept/decline mechanism, so you'll need to add this parameters to url:

```
url = 'http://download.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Medicare-Provider-Charge-Data/Downloads/Medicare_National_HCPCS_Aggregate_CY2017.zip?agree=yes&next=Accept'
```